# increment old value FluentMigrator

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

I'm updating value of column and trying the following code:

```
Update.Table("Table1").Set(new { Column1 = Column1 + 123 });
```

But there is an error `'Column1' doesn't exist in the current context`

How can I fix that? Or maybe how can I rewrite this to get it working?

Comment: Set(new { Column1 = Column1 + 123 }); second Column1 is wrong in this query.

Comment: I know, and I want to fix that.

Comment: do you want update current value plus 123?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```cs
Execute.Sql(@"UPDATE Table1 SET Column1 = Column1 + 123");
```